# Why does my d3.json call return a string and not a number?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

New to D3.

I'm making a `d3.json` call to place a number of points on a map, and would like to set a point's radius value via a value in the source data.  As I understand it, to do that I need to return the value (`d.properties.natscale`) as a number, not a string (it's a number in the source data).  But I keep getting a string.

```
d3.json('mdg-output.json', function(data){
  var populatedPlaces = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.mdg_place)
  var cityPoints = svg.selectAll('circle').data(populatedPlaces.features)
  var  radius = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1000]).range([0,110]);
  cityPoints.enter()
    .attr('r', function(d) {
            // console.log(d.properties)
            return radius(+d.properties.natscale)
    })
        .attr('fill', 'red');
}
```

I'm trying to use the unary `+` operator to convert the output to a number as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704128/how-can-i-efficiently-convert-data-from-string-to-int-within-a-d3-method-chain) and [this](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) link, but it's being returned as a string.  See `r` value in following:

```
<path d="M122.37999457545584,717.0883851792267m0,4.5a4.5,4.5 0 1,1 0,-9a4.5,4.5 0 1,1 0,9z" r="80" fill="red"></path>
```

What am I doing wrong here, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "returned as a string"?  It's generating an HTML attribute in the format `attribute="value"` so it will always be wrapped in quotes

Comment: I need it to not be wrapped in quotes in order to make use of the value - how do I do that?

Comment: A circle in SVG looks like that : `<circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="purple" />`, you need the quotes. In your last example, you have a Path, not a circle

Comment: That's the correct way it should be. In your code what is radius ? And what is d.properties.natscale ?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to store the r value in the html element? If yes, you can add it to the data bonded to the element and use it at required places.

Comment: How do you want to make use of the value?  There are a number of ways that you can access it as a number later

Comment: ok - thanks for all the responses.  I thought I was doing it as Bostok does in his "Let's Make a Map" tutorial - will try a couple of things and post back shortly.  @thatOneGuy - `d.properties.natscale` is a value to represent approximate size of the city - i was hoping to use that as the value for radius.

Comment: Also - why the downvote?  I'm trying to understand how to do this correctly, have done research into similar questions, and have posted my own code on how I've tried to solve this.  Honest question.

Comment: Have updated question for clarity

Comment: What is radius ? If you just want to use d.properties.natscale as the radius, just return that value itself. Also could you tell us what you get when you console log d.properties.natscale

Comment: I was incorrectly trying to use a variable that I hadn't declared.  Console.log'ing d.properties.natscale gives me a number (not a string of a number), but underlyingly it's still in quotes - i don't follow that.  But i also see this isn't the issue I'm trying to answer (ie: why can't i use the value in d.properties.natscale to determine the radius of my points).  Should I delete this question and repost as a new question?  Or edit my code and question to reflect that?

Comment: @Mugshep - you can do either, but your question does need more information... The domain of your scale is ([0,1000]), are the natscale values between 0 and 10000?  What values come back if you log radius(+d.properties.natscale)?  Is it possible to create a code-snippet with some hard-coded values?